# Redshift Product of Column Values

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

How can I generate all possible combination of multiple column in redshift?

For example for all combinations of name and group,

```
| name  | group | value |
+-------+-------+-------|
| a     | 1     | 1     |
| a     | 2     | 1     |
| a     | 3     | 1     |
| b     | 1     | 1     |
| b     | 2     | 1     |
| c     | 3     | 1     |
```

I want to obtain the following:

```
| name  | group | value |
+-------+-------+-------|
| a     | 1     | 1     |
| a     | 2     | 1     |
| a     | 3     | 1     |
| b     | 1     | 1     |
| b     | 2     | 1     |
| b     | 3     | Null  |
| c     | 1     | Null  |
| c     | 2     | Null  |
| c     | 3     | 1     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select n.name, g.group, t.value
from (select distinct name from t) n cross join
     (select distinct group from t) g left join
     t
     on t.name = n.name and t.group = g.group
order by 1, 2;
```

You don't have to use a subquery to get the distinct values if you have them in another table.